# Ajax Page is not post backing for mouse scrolling

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, onclick, onblur

I had a page with 3 update panels... based on textbox changes in updatepanel1, updates the modes of other panels before they click the submit button.

The problem is I created onblur events for the textboxes...once there is a postback everything works fine. But there is one worst case scenario where the user changes the textbox and uses the mouse scroll bar and clicks the submit button. In this case (as onblur event never occurs) I could not able to update the second and third update panels.

One solution I thought was, onclicking the submit button, I was trying to check the previous mode but this will not be possible for my case because of the design issues

Answer (score 0):

You could always attach a Javascript event to the scrollbar to trigger the update as well.

Pseudocode:

```
window.onscroll:
    if contents of textbox have changed:
        do postback
    else
        do nothing
```